# How much memory is required to load an object in R?

Tags: r, memory

I'm trying to load a R object of 4.7GB on my work space. My machine's memory is 16GB and I have 13GB of room. However whenever I try to load that object, there's an error "cannot allocate vector of size 386Kb".
I wonder how much memory should I have for 4.7GB object.
(Window 7, R3.4.1)

The object is result of smbinning function of smbinning package.
I saved it save(smb,file=smb.rda") and trying to load it load(file="smb.rda").
The object was large list of 347MB on my work space. And it was changed to 4.7GB of rda file after saving it. Now 13GB memory is not enough for loading it.

Pleas somebody tell me how to load this object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question, my OS is Window 7 professional.

Comment: I'm trying to load the object saved from smbinning result of smbinning::smbinning(). I saved it as "smb.rda". It was large list of 347mb on my work space. But it was chaged to 4.7GB after saving as rda file. Now 13GB memory is not enough for loading it.

Comment: Still, do you use a 64Bit version? And still, what kind of data are you trying to load. An example would really help, otherwise it is hard to help. Please edit your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 64Bit version. And I commeted file type there.

Comment: How exactly have you saved it? How exactly are you trying to load it?

Comment: save(smb,file="smb.rda") and load(file="smb.rda")

Comment: What does `load(file="smb.rda", verbose = 5)` tell you? (Please edit all relevant information into the question istead of putting it into comments.)

Comment: Roland, I don't know how to show you result. It prints item numbers of list and also ends with error message "cannot allocate vector....."